# Pentaho server init with MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I have a fresh install of Pentaho Server CE 9.3.0.0-428 with MySql 8.028 and connector 8.0.29.

When it's starting it throws many MySQLSyntaxErrorException. It seems a create table statement, which is really wrong: `FSENTRY_NAME varchar not null` (missing the size of varchar type from column definition).

I tried with MySql 5.7.38 and connector 5.1.17 (included in Pentaho bundle) too, without any success.

Here is a log detail

```
2022-07-21 15:49:54,826 ERROR [org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem] failed to initialize file system
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null, FSENTRY_NAME varchar not null, FSENTRY_DATA varbinary null, FSENTRY_LA' at line 1
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[?:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2619) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2569) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:667) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.reallyExec(ConnectionHelper.java:308) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$1.call(ConnectionHelper.java:293) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$1.call(ConnectionHelper.java:289) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper$RetryManager.doTry(ConnectionHelper.java:544) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.ConnectionHelper.exec(ConnectionHelper.java:297) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.util.db.CheckSchemaOperation.run(CheckSchemaOperation.java:89) ~[jackrabbit-data-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DatabaseFileSystem.init(DatabaseFileSystem.java:193) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfigurationParser$6.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfigurationParser.java:1164) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig.getFileSystem(RepositoryConfig.java:926) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:265) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:616) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.16.5.jar:2.16.5]
    at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.jackrabbit.RepositoryFactoryBean.createRepository(RepositoryFactoryBean.java:68) ~[se-jcr-0.9.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.extensions.jcr.RepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBean.java:61) ~[se-jcr-0.9.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
```

Comment: The specific part the error on the second line is enough, BUT we need to see the FULL query causing that error to help.

Comment: The query is not known because it is run by Pentaho at initialization. (This is clearly visible from the error trace: RepositoryFactoryBean.createRepository)
Even if I set the log level to TRACE, the sql statement is not logged